# Is it possible to add double actions in AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to add double actions in Ajax. Both are trigger with the same hyperlink and data-id.

My code looks like:

```
jQuery.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl, {
       action : 'add-to-cart',
       data-id : id
}
```

What I'm doing is:

```
jQuery.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl, {
       action : 'add-to-cart', 'update-cart',
       data-id : id
}
```

Its not working. Should I add a separate code for update-cart?

Comment: No. Each AJAX request is exactly that, a single request.

Comment: AJAX is just HTTP requests that happen to execute in the background. You cannot target a single http request to MULTIPLE urls

Comment: Wait a second, thats just the object passed to the server, you can stick anything into that, but you can't use the same key twice

Comment: Your two examples ... are not the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl, {
       action1 : 'add-to-cart', 
       action2 : 'update-cart',
       dataid  : id
});
```

or

```
jQuery.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl, {
       action  : ['add-to-cart', 'update-cart'],
       dataid  : id
});
```

will pass both to the server, then you just have to catch them